# When does a 2D metric have a 3D-surface representation?

Tags: differential-geometry

Certain non-flat, 2D metrics can be visualized as a 3D surface.  The metric for the surface of the unit sphere, $$ds^2 = d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\,d\phi^2,$$ would be the most familiar example.  Others are more esoteric: in Martin's *General Relativity: A Guide ...*, he visualizes the following metric as a infinitely long trumpet-shaped surface: $$ds^2=\frac{1}{r^2}dr^2 + r^2d\phi^2,$$

What determines whether or not a 2D metric can be described by a 3D surface?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem

Comment: The canonic example: a flat torus has no 3d isometric embedding. The nash embedding theorem statss that every differentiable riemannian (resp pseudoriemannian) n-dimensional manifold can be embedded isometrically into 2n dimensional eucliean (resp minkowski) space.

Comment: So which is it: according to this theorem, is there, or is there not a way to represent a 2D metric, such that its geodesics are described by geodesics on a 3D surface?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question? See also Phys.SE [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37400740#37400740).

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy, your flat torus example doesn't seem correct: http://m.pnas.org/content/109/19/7218

Comment: @theindigamer Interesting! I would think some physically important smoothness condition is violated in doing that though?

Comment: @Qmechanic I should think it would.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy, you may be right on that; the embedding is "only" $C^1$. The authors say that "the normal vector exhibits a fractal behaviour" which would perhaps be undesirable for physics applications.

Comment: It is certainly not an easy question. I would imagine that the Poincaré conjecture takes care of the surfaces with genus $0$. For higher genus surfaces I don't think that the question can be answered that simply.

Comment: It depends on the degree of smoothness you require: If it is $C^1$ then there are no restrictions on the metric (Nash-Kuiper's theorem). Otherwise ($C^2$-smooth), there is no known complete answer, only partial results, e.g. every positively curved metric embeds isometrically in $R^3$.